# Finding coordinate of rectangle in n-dimension

Tags: c++, coordinates, n-dimensional

What is the best way in C++ to calculate the coordinate of a rectangle (hyper-rectangle) in n-dimension?

I have dimensions definition of the rectangle in a 1d vector like:

```
[min1, max1, min2, max2, ...., minN, maxN]
```

For example, in 2d the dimensions, the vector is

```
[min1, max1, min2, max2]
```

And the corner coordinates I am looking for are

```
[min1, min2], [min1, max2], [max1, min2], [max1, max2]
```

How do we do this for a hyper-rectangle in n-dimension?

Comment: I did something similar when trying to make an N-dimensional game of life. You might find [this tiny repository](https://github.com/ktsiam/n-Dimensional-Game-Of-Life) useful (see game.hpp/.cpp)

Comment: Could you show some code? Preferably a [mcve].

Comment: @JesperJuhl I just need an algorithm to calculate the coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That hyper-rectangle has 2^N vertices.

To compute the coordinates of `i`-th vertex where `i` in `[ 0 .. 2^N-1 ]` interval, loop over bits in the `i` from 0 (lowest one) to N-1. If the bit is set, use maximum coordinate for that dimension, if that bit is 0, use minimum coordinate for that dimension.

For example, for cube N=3, it has 8 vertices.

The first one has index 0, `0b000`, you’ll get minimum values for all 3 coordinates.
The last one has index 7, `0b111`, you’ll get maximum values for all 3 coordinates.
The rest of the vertices are in between, you’ll get some combination of min and max coordinates.